# How to fill background color for a specific test in Excel Using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I want to fill the background color of cell whose value is "Fail", I tried the below code but its not working.

```
 ConditionalFormattingRule rule2 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("COUNTIF($J$2:$J$11,J2)=Fail");
    PatternFormatting fill2 = rule2.createPatternFormatting();
    fill2.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
    fill2.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    CellRangeAddress[] regions2 = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf("J2:J10") };
    sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions2, rule2);
```

What is the formula for createconditionalformatting?

Comment: Con you please tell me the Correct formula to used over there, instead of CountIF